# Continuous CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda, gpu

I am writing a CUDA kernel that takes input from device memory, and uses the data in shared memory (which is populated from device memory at kernel launch) to produce the out. The output is placed in the device, which the host reads.

I want this kernel to run continuously so that I do not have to load the data from device memory into shared memory repeatedly. The solution in my mind is that once the kernel is launched, it continuously checks device memory for input. If the input is 0, that means there is no input. If the input is 1, that means the kernel should stop. For all other inputs, the kernel should perform the computation and return the output.

My problem is that I have never seen a kernel that runs continuously and polls the device memory for input. One obvious concern is that this approach may consume too much power if the GPU is operating continuously. Please provide comments/suggestions on this approach.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436228/cuda-infinite-kernel

Comment: Thanks for the link to the existing thread.