# synchronizing device memory access with host thread

Tags: cuda, gpu, synchronize

Is it possible for a CUDA kernel to synchronize writes to device-mapped memory without any host-side invocation (e.g., of `cudaDeviceSynchronize`)? When I run the following program, it doesn't seem that the kernel waits for the writes to device-mapped memory to complete before terminating because examining the page-locked host memory immediately after the kernel launch does not show any modification of the memory (unless a delay is inserted or the call to `cudaDeviceSynchronize` is uncommented):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>

__global__ void func(int *a, int N) {
    int idx = threadIdx.x;

    if (idx < N) {
        a[idx] *= -1;
        __threadfence_system();
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int *a, *a_gpu;
    const int N = 8;
    size_t size = N*sizeof(int);

    cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost);
    cudaHostAlloc((void **) &a, size, cudaHostAllocMapped);
    cudaHostGetDevicePointer((void **) &a_gpu, (void *) a, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%i ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    func<<<1, N>>>(a_gpu, N);
    // cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%i ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    cudaFreeHost(a);
}
```

I'm compiling the above for sm_20 with CUDA 4.2.9 on Linux and running it on a Fermi GPU (S2050).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A kernel launch will immediately return to the host code before any kernel activity has occurred.  Kernel execution is in this way asynchronous to host execution and *does not block* host execution.  So it's no surprise that you have to wait a bit or else use a barrier (like cudaDeviceSynchronize()) to see the results of the kernel.

As described [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution):

> In order to facilitate concurrent execution between host and device,
>   some function calls are asynchronous: *Control is returned to the host
>   thread before the device has completed the requested task*. These are:
>
> - Kernel launches;
> - Memory copies between two addresses to the same device memory;
> - Memory copies from host to device of a memory block of 64 KB or    less;
> - Memory copies performed by functions that are suffixed with Async;
> - Memory set function calls.

This is all intentional of course, so that you can use the GPU and CPU simultaneously.  If you don't want this behavior, a simple solution as you've already discovered is to insert a barrier.  If your kernel is producing data which you will immediately copy back to the host, you don't need a separate barrier.  The cudaMemcpy call after the kernel will wait until the kernel is completed before it begins it's copy operation.

I guess to answer your question, you are wanting kernel launches to be synchronous without you having even to use a barrier (why do you want to do this?  Is adding the cudaDeviceSynchronize() call a problem?)  It's possible to do this:

> "Programmers can globally disable asynchronous kernel launches for all
>   CUDA applications running on a system by setting the
>   CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING environment variable to 1. This feature is
>   provided for debugging purposes only and should never be used as a way
>   to make production software run reliably. "

If you want this `synchronous` behavior, it's better just to use the barriers (or depend on another subsequent cuda call, like cudaMemcpy).    If you use the above method and depend on it, your code will break as soon as somebody else tries to run it without the environment variable set.  So it's really not a good idea.

Comment: I was trying to understand whether __threadfence_system() effectively serves as a device-side barrier of sorts; see the final comment by Greg Smith [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436228/cuda-infinite-kernel).

Comment: Also see section B.5 in the CUDA 4.2 Programming Guide.

Comment: __threadfence *is* a device barrier of sorts.  But it is only a barrier for device activity (i.e. device code subsequent to the threadfence call).  Host activity is still asynchronous.  The host thread is released immediately to continue after launching the kernel.  To stop host side activity, you need a host side barrier.

Comment: But what effect does __threadfence_system have upon "host threads for page-locked host memory accesses" if one must still employ a host-side barrier?

Comment: __threadfence_system() blocks the *calling thread* (that is the device thread) until data written to host page locked memory is visible (to host threads).  That means that after the __threadfence_system() call releases the device thread to continue, you can expect that any host thread accessing page-locked memory will see any results that were written prior to the barrier.  But it doesn't *block* any host threads, at any time, ever.  So if your host thread happens to read before that point, it may get other results.  Since none of this blocks a host thread, they are still asynchronous.

Comment: @Robert Crovella  This looks like true, but I have the same problem such as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417346/cuda-pinned-memory-flushing-from-the-device I use `__threadfence_system()` but it does not make visible any changes in host-mapped memory which has done by GPU.