# Does the CUDA TCC driver work with geforce cards on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, cuda

I have 4 GTX 570's on a windows 7 machine. According to the programming guide Peer-to-peer memory copy should work on Geforce and Quadro as well as Tesla

> Memory copies can be performed between the memories of two different devices. When a unified address space is used for both devices (see Unified Virtual Address Space), this is done using the regular memory copy functions mentioned in Device Memory. Otherwise, this is done using cudaMemcpyPeer(), cudaMemcpyPeerAsync(), cudaMemcpy3DPeer(), or cudaMemcpy3DPeerAsync()

However in order to use it on windows, I need to instal the TCC driver. Can I install the TCC driver  for geforce cards on windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the Windows TCC driver only supports Tesla and selected Quadro cards based on the Fermi and Kepler architectures.

Comment: What did you mean when said "selected Quadro cards" and on which of Quadro cards TCC works?

Comment: @Alex: I mean exactly what I said - certain Fermi & Kepler based Quadro cards (basically those that share silicon with Telsa cards) are supported by the TCC driver. That *probably* means desktop Quadro 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000. The Windows documentation and nvidia-smi itself has a list of supported GPUs